# I have programmed an application in UWP. How do I create it into a downloadable, executable windows application?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

[image]

This image is the application that I have created in my file explorer. I do not know how I am supposed to make this app into a normal windows application like every other windows app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be downloadable form the Microsoft Store follow these two steps:

1. First you have to create a package. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps
2. The package can then be uploaded to the Microsoft Store. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/

If you want an "normal windows application" you have chosen the wrong project type. To create a "normal windows application" use the "WPF Application" project type. Depending on the complexity of your project you have to change your code to work with the "WPF Application" project type.